# Regex match with capture groups

Tags: regex

I need some help with regex capture groups.

In the string below, I need it to match only if "skynet" is in the string and need two capture groups, accountid to capture the 12 digit account # and role to capture everything after the dash before "skynet":

> aws-123456789012-skynet-tenant-134-admin

I have the regex below, which is almost what I need, except I need the role to be "skynet-tenant-134-admin", not "-tenant-134-admin":

```
^(?:[^-]*-)(?<accountid>\d{12})(?:[^-]*-)(?<target>skynet)(?<role>.*)
```

The goal is to only match if "skynet" appears after the second dash and two capture groups containing accountid (123456789012) and role (skynet-tenant-134-admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest the capturing groups and put `target` inside `role`

```
^(?:[^-]*-)(?<accountid>\d{12})(?:[^-]*-)(?<role>(?<target>skynet).*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qyh7EZ/1)

Which you might shorten to without the use of the non capturing groups `(?:`

```
^[^-]*-(?<accountid>\d{12})[^-]*-(?<role>(?<target>skynet).*)
```

Comment: Thank you, that does exactly what I need.  One other question, If I need the same thing except it should match anything except "skynet", how would I change this regex?

Comment: If you want to match anything except skynet, if you use a programming language you might replace skynet with an empty string. Or you could use a  capturing group and replace with the first capturing group https://regex101.com/r/GABEBo/1

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't using a programming language.  This is for an Okta/AWS integration, where I have to supply just the regex.  I'll take a look at your second option and see if I can incorporate that in.  Thanks again for your help.